# WPF freezes when changing screen resolution or multi screen layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, screen-resolution

App is similar to Snagit app which popup from the top edge of the screen on hover. All works fine, including animations etc. until I either change the display resolution or as I`m working in multiple screen environment, change the screens layout. The app then freezes on first animation and changes background color to the color which should be displayed when the app is in up position (retracted). Sorry for the confusing description, I attached some screenshots and code.

.Net 4.7.2

**1st** image shows the app as it should work with grey background in slide down position when hovering over.

**2nd** image shows the broken app after changing resolution or multiscreen layout - frozen in slide down position with red background - hovering over will fix the problem.

**3rd** image shows the correct red color of the app in retracted position.

**4th** gif shows the correct animation with mouse on, mouse off triggers. The window slides down when started first time (to show the user where it is) and slides back - this happens always on startup.

**5th** gif shows how the app is freezing up after resolution has been changed, hovering over releases the lock and app is back working again.

[image: This is normal behavior when hover over the window slides down with grey background color]

[image: The window freezes in slide down position with color changed to RED]

[image: Should be RED only when in UP position - retracted]

[image]

[image]

XAML Storyboard below with animations on startup, on hover etc.

```
<Window x:Class="DockPanel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Icon="DockPanel.ico"
    Title="MainWindow" Name="DockPanel" Height="275" Width="530" 
    Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual" 
    Top="-241" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True">

<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Startup animation - when program starts -->
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowDownStartup">

        <!-- Slide down -->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.3" DecelerationRatio="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel">

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="0">

                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase Power="4" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>

            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <!--Slide up the window-->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1.0" DecelerationRatio="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel">

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="-264">

                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase Power="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>

            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


        <!-- Change color to Red when up -->
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="MyApp" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource BackgroundRedAnimateUp}" KeyTime="00:00:0.3" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>


    <!-- Animation when mouse over -->
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowDown">


        <!-- Change window background color to default when window down -->
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MyApp" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource BackgroundDefault}" KeyTime="00:00:0.2" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <!-- Slide window down to 0 -->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.6" Duration="0:0:0.4" DecelerationRatio="0.8"  
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel" >

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="0">

                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase Power="3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>

            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>


        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>


    <!-- Animation when mouse leave -->
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowUp" Completed="StoryboardWindowUp_Completed">

        <!-- Slide window up to -219 -->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.4" DecelerationRatio="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.4" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Top)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel">

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="-264">

                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <PowerEase Power="2" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>

            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        <!-- Change background color to Red after window is up -->
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1.0" Storyboard.TargetName="MyApp" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource BackgroundRedAnimateUp}" KeyTime="00:00:0.4" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


    </Storyboard>


    <!--Change the window size to 550-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="ExtendWindow">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="00:00:0.3" AccelerationRatio="0.4" DecelerationRatio="0.6" 
                         From="530" To="580" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <!--Change the window size back to original size-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="RetractWindow">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.3" Duration="00:00:0.3" AccelerationRatio="0.4" DecelerationRatio="0.6" 
                         From="580" To="530" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="DockPanel"/>
    </Storyboard>


</Window.Resources>


<Window.Triggers>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowDownStartup}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowDown}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowUp}"/>
    </EventTrigger>

</Window.Triggers>
```

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any point where you're ending your storyboards.  This means that every storyboard is still running in the background.  Try ending your window up at the beginning of your mouse leave trigger, and your window down at the beginning of your mouse enter trigger.

Comment: Should i just use StopStoryboard with a BeginStoryboardName target to stop it in the same trigger

Comment: When you use StopStoryboard any changes that your storyboard made are reverted, so it depends on what your storyboard does.  As such it's going to be a try it and see if it's what you want.

Comment: I`v added animated gif to show the correct behavior of the app, the second image shows the broken app once the resolution was changed or screen layout. How do you end the the window up at the beginning of mouse leave?

Comment: This is the microsoft example of using the various components. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-use-event-triggers-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts

Comment: Thanks, I have found and followed that example. I tried a few things and nothing worked.

Comment: If you mouse over and back when it's gone wrong, does it start working again?  If you run it with a debugger attached do you get any output when you change the screen resolution?

Comment: After hovering over the app starts working again. I just attached gif to show that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210740/discussion-between-phoenix-stoneham-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found an ugly (temporary) solution to my problem via DisplaySettingsChaned event handler. Every time the resolution change has been detected I`m restarting the app. I admit, this is not a perfect solution but it will do for now until i find something better.

Any better ideas appreciated.

```
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
```

And via handler:

```
Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
```